# Trying to update name and date in a highcharts column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a highcharts column chart with several sets of data. I need to be able to change the name of a series , the data and add or remove series. 
I am unable to update an existing series. This is a short example of the code:

```
        var InvChart = $('#Inv-summary').highcharts();
        var master=[];
        var type1 = "stock";
        var range1 = 1100000;
        var range2 = -750000;
        master.push({name: type1 ,data: [range1, range2]}); 
        InvChart.series[0].setData(master,true);
```

thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- change name of serie - [series.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update)
- [add serie](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries)
- [remove serie](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.remove)
- update data in serie can be achieved by setData, as you have